# HTML - listas anidadas (válidas w3c)

Tags: html, html5

¿Hay alguna forma de construir listas anidadas (html) que sean válidas (w3c)?, he intentado esto y no pasan la validación (https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea):

```
<ul>
  <li>aaa
    <ol>
      <li>bbb</li>
    <ol>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
    <ol>
      <li>bbb</li>
    <ol>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El primer error que veo, es que no estás cerrando las etiquetas `<ol>`
Y en segundo lugar, estás intentando anidar un `<ol>` como si fuera un `<li>`

Es decir, estás intentando hacer esto:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <ol></ol>
</ul>
```

Lo cula no esválido, ya que los elementos `<ul>` y `<ol>` son iguales, ambos son contenedores de listas (ordenada y desordenada).

Por lo que el esquema válido sería:

```html
 <ul>
      <li>aaa
        <ol>
          <li>bbb</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul>
      <li>aaa</li>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li>bbb</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul type="cricle">
    <li>Animal</h3>
         <ol type="1">
             <b><li>Felinos</b>
                 <ol type="i">
                   <li>Selva 
                         <a name="Selva"></a>
                       <ul type="drisk">
                          <li>Tigre
                           <li>Pantera
                           <li>Jaguar
                        </ul>
                   <li>Sabana
                       <ol type="A">
                          <li>Leon
                           <li>Leopardo
                        </ol>
                  </ol>
             <b><li>Aves</b>
                    <ol type="a">
                          <li>Aguila
                           <li>halcon
                        </ol>
             <b><li>Maritimos</b>
          </ol>
    <h3><li>frutas</h3>
          <ol type="1">
                  <li>Melon
                  <li>Uva
                  <li>Fresa
             </ol>
    <h3><li>cosas</h3>
        <ol type="A">
              <li>Libro
              <li>Silla
                   <ol type="i">
                    <li>mesedora
                   <li>Fija
                    </ol>
              <li>Arbol
          </ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: Deberías poner una explicación a la respuesta, no solo el código sin más.